# Removing Linear drift from an oscillating data

Tags: fitting

I have an array of 800,000 data measured at 1.1s time gap. It is oscillating data but has clear linear drift. I want to remove this linear drift. But the estimates by `FindFit` and `Fit` has been very bad.
Here is my attempt with `FindFit`

```
model = e*x + noise[[1]];  
fit = FindFit[noise, model, {e}, x]
{e -> -0.0430509}
```

The value of `e` is quite visibly wrong. It should be arround `-0.040`. Is there better ways to find and remove linear trends from datas? Thank you very much.

The data can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xg2w6d4a6bpaejk/data.dat

Comment: Can you provide the data set ?

Comment: @Sektor I have updated the link to the data.

Comment: I am already downloading it :)

Comment: Please let me know, if you have a better way.

Comment: Can you try the following ? `swd = StationaryWaveletTransform[data, DaubechiesWavelet[2], 8]` and then `ListLogLogPlot[
 data - .93 Flatten@Reverse@swd[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, "Values"]]`

Comment: Where `data` is your data set. Also can you show me what the desired result looks like ?

Comment: I do not have a desired result but as you can see from the data, there is a distinct linear drift in the data and I just want to remove it. So that the oscillation is more or less arround certain value.

Comment: What do you think of the results you are getting after executing my code ?

Comment: I got a convex curve with the `ListLogLogPlot` which was not quite what I was looking for.

Comment: I just need to remove the linear drift and to be honest, I have no working knowledge of Stationary Wavelet Transformations. For now, I just used the simple Least Square method and got a satisfactory result. I did: 
`noise = [imported data from data file];` `t = 1.1*Range[0,Length[noise]-1];` `mat = Transpose[{ConstantArray[1, Length[noise]], t}];` `LeastSquares[mat, noise]` and got `{8.24575*10^8, -0.0402358}` which gives good enough estimate of linear drift.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Fit` seems to work fine, you just need to include your 1.1 step size.

```
data = Import["data.dat", "List"];
d = Thread[{1.1 Range@Length@d, d}];
Fit[d, {1, x}, x]
```

> `8.24575*10^8 - 0.0402358 x`

So now we have the -0.040 that you wanted.  It looks ok by eye:

```
Show[ListPlot[d, Joined -> True], 
     Plot[8.245747660409383`*^8 - 0.04023578596262912` x, {x, 1.1, 1.1 Length@d},
       PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: fit]

We can now subtract the linear drift from the data:

```
dflat = {First@#, Last@# - (8.245747660409383`*^8 - 0.04023578596262912` First@#)}& /@ d;
ListPlot[dflat, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

**Edit:** We can take this even further.  Let's interpolate over every 5000th point:

```
i = Interpolation[dflat[[;; ;; 5000]]];
Show[ListPlot[dflat, Joined -> True], 
     Plot[i[x], {x, dflat[[1, 1]], dflat[[-1, 1]]}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Then subtract this from the data:

```
dsharp = Quiet@{First@#, Last@# - i[First@#]} & /@ dflat;
ListPlot[dsharp, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Now we're really just oscillating around a fixed value.  But I have no idea what your data represents.  Maybe this is what you want, or maybe this is just the noise.

Comment: Thank you very much this helps a lot. The final result is what I was looking for too. :)

Comment: @jason Then as a further though, you might not want to just take every 5000th point raw for the interpolation.  You might want to smooth it our first.  `MedianFilter` could be a good choice.